# What is wrong in the following calculation for the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 0 & 3 & 0 &      1 & 0 & 0\\
 4 & 0 & 0 &      0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 5 &      0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$

Exchange the first and the second columns:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 3 & 0 & 0 &      0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 4 & 0 &      1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 5 &      0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$

Divide the rows by $3$, $4$, and $5$ respectively:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 &      0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 &      \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 &      0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5}
\end{array}\right]$

Obviously, the result is not the inverse of the initial matrix. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use column transformations, this is what you're *actually* doing:
$AI = A \Rightarrow\\
AIE_1 = AE_1,\ \text{where $E_1$ is an elementary matrix}\\
\vdots\\
AIE_1\ldots E_n = AE_1\ldots E_n = I \Rightarrow\\
IE_1\ldots E_n = A^{-1}$

When you use row transformations, on the other hand, you're left-multiplying by elementary matrices:
$E_1'\ldots E_n'IA = E_1'\ldots E_n'A = I \Rightarrow\\
E_1'\ldots E_n'I = A^{-1}$

You can't combine the two as the same identity matrix cannot be on the left and right of $A$ at the same time, so to speak. And if you use two different identity matrices (as $IAI$, so that the augmented matrix is $[I|A|I]$), then neither one will be transformed into $A^{-1}$.

Comment: So, I simply have to avoid mixing row- and column- operations. Thanks!

Comment: That's right. You can get a diagonal matrix in the second step by interchanging the rows.

Comment: Either I exchange the rows first or I divide the columns after my first step, right ?

Comment: In both cases, I get the right inverse.

Comment: Yes, either way is fine.

Comment: In your comment, you mean the first step, right ?

Comment: Well, I meant if you do that in the first step, you'll have a diagonal matrix in the second step.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul work on columns or on rows, never on both.